# What's the $\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{1+e^\frac{1}{x-1}}{1-e^\frac{1}{x-1}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{1+e^\frac{1}{x-1}}{1-e^\frac{1}{x-1}}$

It's always giving me $\infty$ when x approaches 1 from both sides, no matter what I do.
I'm trying to solve it without l'Hopital's Rule or Taylor Series.

Answer (score 2):

Let $t=\frac{1}{x-1} \to \infty$. Then$$\frac{1+e^t}{1-e^t} = \frac{e^{-t} +1}{e^{-t} -1} \to \frac{1}{-1} =-1$$ This is true assuming you mean $x\to 1^+$.

If $x\to 1^{-}$, then $t\to -\infty$ and the limit evaluates to $1$.

Hence, the limit doesn’t exist.

Comment: $ t \to \infty$ as $x \to 1^+$ and $ t \to -\infty$ as $x \to 1^-.$

Comment: @AsemAbdelraouf True, fixed.

Comment: Error in first line: $1/-1=-1$

Comment: @Tavish why 1+e^t = e^(-t) + 1

Comment: @GreasyLlama I have divided the top and bottom by $e^t$.

Comment: @Tavish aight thanks mate.